# Why does Adobe Premiere CC change my "Ease Out" keyframe interpolation to "Bezier"?

Tags: premiere, adobe, keyframes

In Adobe Premiere CC, I keep trying to set my position keyframe's temporal interpolation to "Ease Out". After I set it, I recheck the context menus immediately, and it has reverted to "Bezier".  Why does it do that, and how can I get it to keep the temporal interpolation that I set?

[image]

Comment: Have you checked if the Ease Out is applied though? What does the keyframe graph look like?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The keyframe graph looks like a parabola - like the path of a rocket shooting up, reaching the apex, and falling back down. I'm almost certain that's a Bezier.  Plus I wouldn't trust it if it said "Bezier" even though it was "Ease Out". I tried adjusting the keyframe graph but I just don't like the interpolation, and it doesn't match the other videos I've made that use Ease Out / Ease In.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. It's a bit confusing, but as you can see in your screenshot, the *Temporal Interpolation* context menu is split in two parts. The part above the seperating line (see your screenshot) sets the keyframe type. From the [documentation](https://helpx.adobe.com/premiere-pro/using/controlling-effect-changes-using-keyframe.html):

> - **Linear:** Creates a uniform rate of change between keyframes.
> - **Bezier:** Lets you manually adjust the shape of the graph, and the rate of change, on either side of a keyframe. You can create very
>     smooth changes using this method.
> - **Auto Bezier:** Creates a smooth rate of change through a keyframe. As you change a keyframe’s value, the Auto Bezier direction handles
>     change to maintain a smooth transition between keyframes.
> - **Continuous Bezier:** Creates a smooth rate of change through a keyframe. However, unlike the Auto Bezier interpolation method,
>     Continuous Bezier lets you adjust direction handles manually. As you
>     change the shape of a graph on one side of a keyframe, the shape on
>     the other side of the keyframe changes to maintain a smooth
>     transition.
> - **Hold:** Changes a property value without gradual transition (sudden effect changes). The graph following a keyframe with the Hold
>     interpolation applied appears as a horizontal straight line.

The two options below the seperating line – Ease In & Ease Out – are rather like presets or shortcuts. They switch the keyframe type (since easing in/out requires [bézier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) and is therefore not possible in *Hold* or *Linear* modes) and set a smooth transition. If you open up the graph view in the *Effect Settings* panel, you can see the effect the two options have:

[image: linear]

Linear.

[image: ease in]

Ease In.

[image: ease in and out]

Ease In + Ease Out.

You can still adjust the velocity interpolation manually using the Bézier handles seen in the screenshots above.

Comment: Thanks for this description and all the screenshots. Are you saying that the "Ease In" and "Ease Out" never show a checkmark next to them?? That would be REALLY confusing. And that's what I'm seeing:  there is no checkmark next to Ease In or Ease Out after I select them. I'm almost certain that I've seen a checkmark next to each of them in other projects.... I'll have to research this later, when I can access my project again.

Comment: @BrettFromLA Yeah, they don't. Well I said it would be confusing :D They are more like a shortcut to get you started or provide a quick easing transition, not a keyframe type of their own. Could be that they used to show checkmarks in previous versions, but I've just checked in the current version of Premiere Pro CC and there are no checkmarks. I think that's also why there's a seperating line above them.

Comment: Well since that's the case, I'll mark your answer as the answer! I still don't understand why they're in the drop-down list if they can't be selected. That's just terrible UX. (When I say "can't be selected", I mean that when you select it, you can never tell whether you actually selected it or just meant to select it, because there's no indication - checkmark - that you selected it.)